# C++ How to determine time zone using latitude and longitude

Tags: c++, datetime, c++11, timezone-offset

I'm looking for any C++ library or in built C++ APIs to determine time zone if latitude and longitude are given as an input. please share here if there is any such.

I have UTC time with latitude and longitude information, now I would like to convert that to time zone. for example `2013-07-10 02:52:49,-44.490947,171.220966 to Pacific/Auckland,2013-07-10T14:52:49`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates shows how to do it in other languages. You can use this to get started.

Comment: @PeterSkarpetis, Thanks, I have gone though it but could not get any pointers with that. This [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro) explains, how to get time zone using locations, but unfortunately as per the [link] (https://google.github.io/google-api-cpp-client/latest/available_service_apis.html) google map api is no more available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Google Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/start) or [TimeZoneDb](https://timezonedb.com/api).

Comment: I managed to get it done using google map api and curl in C++. I followed document at the [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/start). And used jsonCPP to parse the response.